# Creating apps for a team in Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have my own developer account, but at the moment I am working with a client who will have their app uploaded to their account. I am setup as an admin on their team, and I can manage provisioning profiles and such, but I cannot find a way to even attempt to access their "manage apps" section for itunes Connect. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the "Manage User" section in the iTunes connect main page ? From here, you can manage the users in the team and change their roles. I had an similar issue, with the admin of a team unable to manage provisioning profiles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, while a single account can admin multiple development teams in the developer portal, it can only be attached to a single itunesConnect account. I had to ask the client to add a different email to the itunes connect account.